# Rails 7 & Active Record - ArgumentError: Unknown key: :source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I am working on a Rails 7 upgrade from Rails 6 and I constantly get an error regarding the `source` key on active record relationships.

I have multiple places like:
`has_many :custom_accounts, through: :services, source: :bank_account`

and get the error:

```
ArgumentError:

Unknown key: :source. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :primary_key, :foreign_key, :dependent, :validate, :inverse_of, :strict_loading, :autosave, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :counter_cache, :join_table, :index_errors
```

I cannot find any documentation or other posts regarding a deprecation of the `:source` key. And these worked before upgrading Rails to 7.0.3 (and automatically active_record as well)

I also tried changing this into `class_name` & `foreign_key`, but that does not work as it suggests adding a `source`.

Comment: Your issue is already 5 months old so I don't know if it helps but I would like to share what I found out. I came across the same error updating from Rails 6 to 6.1 here. It is really frustrating that they don't document changes like this. What is found is that using the source option has became more strict you must use it in combination with the through option like you have here. I'm not sure if it solves your problem but perhaps you need the source_type option as well?

Comment: thank you, @Smek! This was baffling me, too.